# Tomcat port 8080 not accessible on Windows server

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, server, tomcat9

I have created an AWS EC2 windows instance, and deploy Java web application on tomcat which is running on port 8080, but it is not accessing by web browser.
When i Turn Off the Firewall of AWS windows server then it is gets accessible but not accessible when i turn on the Firewall.

I have open inbound and outbound port(8080) into windows firewall advance setting but no result.

Anyone can help me please like how can i change the firewall settings or something else to access the same.

[InBound security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ablfX.png)

[OutBound security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6urlK.png)

Comment: What AMI ( or windows version do you use?)